# Misunderstanding of .net checkbox

Tags: vb.net

Situation is as follows:

I have form on which is tabcontrol and inside firs tab with autoscroll property=true  is complex GUI where first control is checkbox. I uses windows 7 with default theme and I don't see anyhow when checkbox is focused. And more, key events for this control don't work at all so when I press key.Up focus automatically jumps to last control on my gui and I would like to stop focus at checkbox. But e.keycode = keys.Up under keydown event of checkbox was never fired so I can't set e.handled to true.

Do I do something wrong or .net checkbox have "builtin issues"?
On this checkbox tabindex is set to 0 and tabstop to true.

Comment: The simple explanation is that the checkbox doesn't have the focus, some other control does.  Fix the TabIndex properties of the controls or use the checkbox' Select() method in the constructor.

Comment: Can't find any error in my taborder. More interesting is that in described situation event PreviewKeyDown works as expected. Can I suppress keydown somehow under this event handler?